# jQuery($) not available in module file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle my code.
This is snippet from my main.js file where I am loading jQuery

**main.js**

```
    var $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery)
    $('someSelctor').on('rest of the code.') // This is working fine
    var importFile = require('someExport.js')
    importFile.someFunction();
```

**someExport.js**

```
module.exports = {
   someFunction :function(){
    $('someSelector').on(' some other code') // Error here. $ is not a function
   }
}
```

I also tried by load jquery like `require('jquery')` in `someExport.js`. But that does not resolved the issue.
As `jquery` is already loaded by `main.js` do I need to load it again.Also how can use jquery in someExport.js file

Thanks you

Comment: Are you wrapping your code inside IIFE main.js ?

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader ? See also https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html . Globals take extra work in webpack.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal no it is not IIFE

Comment: console.log($) => not defined?

Comment: @bebraw thanks for the link ProvidePlugin resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require jQuery in `someExport.js` :

```
var $ = require(jquery);
module.exports = {
   someFunction :function(){
    $('someSelector').on(' some other code') // Error here. $ is not a function
   }
}
```

Comment: found another way of resolving it as suggested by bebraw.We can use webpack Provideplugin 
https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you just add this in your module ?

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This force the add of jQuery by creating a specific script.

However not sure it is optimised (I used it for Tampermonkey script).

Comment: Webpack is a module loader & If I do this then there is no use of module loader like webpack